# Two tags pointing at the same thing: [farsi] and [persian]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request, languages

Excuse my ignorance for not coming up with a punny title unlike many meta posts about tags, but I'm a native speaker of Persian/Farsi and I just noticed that both the tags [persian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/persian) and [farsi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/farsi) exist and I have no clue why.

["Persian" is the English translation of "Farsi"](http://www.u.arizona.edu/~karimi/Persian%20or%20Farsi.pdf). (The article proceeds to draw a useful and clear distinction between what to call "Persian" and what to call "Farsi", but you don't need to read past the first page) The distinctions between these two terms are rather arbitrary at this point, and I do not believe anyone here differentiates between them.

So should one tag become a synonym of the other, or is there an obscure reason for keeping the two tags kicking that I'm not aware of?

Comment: Burninate both!

Comment: Hmm, not sure @BJB, we do have tags like [tag:arabic], [tag:chinese-locale], [tag:tamil], [tag:french] and perhaps a bunch of others that I missed.

Comment: Burninate all of those too. They don't help categorize questions.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure, but shouldn't you be writing an answer now @BJB?

Comment: At least *some* of the language tags seem important to me because they describe a particular **writing system** ('script') and its inherent problems with, historically, Western languages oriented programming. Is making [tag:farsi] and [tag:persian] synonyms of [tag:arabic] okay [1]? (Looking at the questions, [tag:french] can safely be destroyed. *Zut alors!*) [1] "Okay" in the most broad sense possible; technically, culturally, morally, personally – pick any.

Comment: @Jongware Persian uses the Arabic script, but it has four more letters. Unfortunately, I do not know whether this makes a difference, but for what it's worth, Arabic script is a subset of Persian, regardless of the history.

Comment: Is the difference small enough to consider it a superset? `[italian]`, for example, does not exist, although it uses a few letters less than the full Latin set. I believe a native user such as you may have a definitely valid opinion on this.

Comment: (Additional thought) If someone experiences a programming related problem with Arabic *anywhere in the world*: it's the name of the *script* and not the language, regardless of language specific diversions. I'm strongly leaning towards that's how these questions should be tagged, and not with the name of any language.

Comment: Yes @Jongware, it is only four letters. The main problem is that I lack any background in hitting dead-ends with RTL languages and someone who actually has may be of more help here. But certainly the difference is very, very small. I think people in favor of keeping the tag would only argue about the tag name; i.e. "But Arabic isn't Persian!" and all that.

Comment: "Farsi" to "Persian" is like "Deutsch" to "German". What do you do when you see a "Deutsch" tag? I think it should be automatically corrected to "German". If so then Farsi should also be corrected to Persian.

Comment: I made burninate requests for both [persian](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315921/pull-out-the-persian-rug-from-under-the-feet-of-this-tag) and [farsi](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315920/phase-out-farsi)

Comment: @dashesy The word "Farsi" is frequently used in English to refer to the language, unlike "Deutsch."

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As @Jongware is suggesting, I would have thought language tags should be more targeted at **alphabet systems** and **language features**, rather than a specific language.

Many language questions I've seen are more related to how to deal with specific "quirks" of a language, such as [Remove Accents From Accented Characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17561839/remove-accents-from-accented-characters), rather than a language itself. So feature tags like [diacritics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/diacritics), and alphabets like [cyrillic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cyrillic) are more useful for categorizing questions, than say [russian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/russian).

I don't think there is a clear answer, because it may not be specific enough to tag a [writing system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_writing_systems) ([cyrillic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cyrillic)), but it is probably too specific to tag a [ISO 639 language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes) ([german](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/german)). On balance tho, I think a writing system is close enough considering the types of questions asked regarding how to handle them.

(In that vein, I would say it is valid to add a [klingon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/klingon) tag, because that refers to the various languages using the [Klingon alphabets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klingon_alphabets)).

Answer (score 13):

Both tags do not help to categorize questions. The same is true for all other natural languages like French or Polish.

Comment: And so, by logical inference, it's okay to add a tag for [klingon](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=klingon)! The next step in [justifying Klingon's addition to Unicode](http://www.klingonwiki.net/En/Unicode) is nigh!

Comment: In my humble opinion, some software and programming related problems are (human/natural) language-specific. In other words, questions tagged with a (human/natural) language tag are not necessarily unhelpful.

Comment: @DamkerngT. sure, they might be related but a tag does not help to categorize these questions. Often it is a problem about encoding or right-to-left languages which is not limited to a single language.

Comment: My old answer from [meta.se]: [Tags for natural languages help in content categorization and searching of posts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/179681/7586)

Comment: @Kobi Your post led to the burnidation of [english], most of the answers agreed that these tags are not useful. Do you agree with me or not?

Comment: The more common term is [natural language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language), not "real language".

Answer (score -3):

`Farsi` is the language of `Persian` are the people and culture. That simple. Just as Dutch and French are languages and Swiss are the people and culture.

So technically, questions based around the language should be marked by `farsi` (grammar, directionality, encoding, code pages, etc.) and questions based upon culture should be marked by `persian` (calendar, do-s and do-not-s, symbols, etc.).

Why either of them can exist, together or not, is explained [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/316048/3994502) where it has drawn me to this thread.

Comment: Well, I am a native speaker of Persian and I do not agree with this arbitrary distinction.

Answer (score -12):

"Farsi" is the current language of [Iran](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iran), but "Persian" is the Persian language from each country, Iran, [Afghanistan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Afghanistan) or [Tajikistan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tajikistan).

The tags often builds from users and can be reported to moderators.

Everyone can create a tag just after getting 1,500 reputation points.

**More information:**

*https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags*

If you saw offensive tags, report those

> It will also show up in the moderator tools new tag report.

**I guess maybe it was created because of [SEO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_optimization)**.

Comment: So *if* the tags are useful, shouldn't we just let "Persian" be, since I don't see a need for a more localized tag?

Comment: I'm not sure what is your opinion on the subject.