# Phase out [Farsi]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, burninate-request

The tag [farsi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/farsi) has 54 questions linked at the moment, none of which it is the only tag to.

I believe it constitutes a meta tag:

- It's ambigous. The programming meaning is unclear.
- It's not descriptive. No programming question tagged with just [farsi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/farsi) would be useful.
- It's superflous. The tag adds no discernible important new information to the questions that have it.

In conclusion, I propose we burninate this tag.

Related: *[Pull out the [Persian] rug from under the feet of this tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315921/pull-out-the-persian-rug-from-under-the-feet-of-this-tag)*

Comment: This tag is farsical.

Comment: Actually, I think it holds value, as it relates to attempts to encode Farsi writing using computer programs. This may well be of value to searchers, or to experts on encoding Farsi writing using computer programs.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit In that case, a tag specifying that specific set of characters would be better instead.

Comment: That's what this tag is. What's the problem?

Comment: "No programming question tagged with just farsi would be useful" - I think it would - you can search html5 and farsi in Google and find plenty of valuable links to both Persian and Farsi and the related language requirements for programming.

Comment: Farsi has lots of tricky programming problems.  Right-to-left layout, non-standard calendar, non-arabic digits, tricky orthography, 3 alphabets.  Intentionally preventing one programmer versed in the language from finding another is very unproductive.  Don't kill what you don't know.

Comment: When did being the only tag on some questions become an important characteristic for a tag?

Comment: Funnily enough, the tag searching on Stack might be improved here, as, if you put either persian or farsi into the search box, the only things that turn up are references to these discussions about the tags. No wonder they are not thought to be useful when there are actually 54 questions as per the OP..

Comment: @Steve perhaps you typed into the [meta search](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=farsi) instead of the [main site search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=farsi)?

Comment: @ryanyuyu ahh...how did you guess? oops! Perhaps there would still be a case for merging the two though rather than having them be separate: The one calls the other - that way because they would both essentially be on the same topic you would get at them all with one search. It would work better as a search term then.

Comment: @Steve I think it's better for me that they remain separate.  It's much better than an extra flag for something like `meta:true`.  Also, combining the search might take a decent amount of backend development.

Comment: @ryanyuyu I see - I thought the backend modifications would have been the easy bit.

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you for being the first one to mention anything making Farsi so different it might need its own tag. Now if someone would elaborate on that in an answer...

Comment: @erickson the [blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) linked to from eg [the Meta tag page about meta-tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/meta-tags/info). The blog post fails, unfortunately, to properly define "can't work", but that's neither here nor there; it's become a thing that people reference.

Comment: The five-tags-per-question limit takes care of reining in the use of tags. Language tags *have* merit, even if they are vastly outnumbered by the use of other tags. Are we running out of storage space or something? Fair enough, join `farsi` and `persian` as alias, but that should be it.

Answer (score 18):

This has been discussed earlier on MSE. Tags for natural languages help in content categorization and searching of relevant posts. These should not be burninated.

Quoting answer posted by [kobi](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/7586/kobi) for [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179681/tags-for-natural-languages-help-in-content-categorization-and-searching-of-posts):

> Language tags are certainly useful.
>
> - Some questions *are* language specific. People asked for examples: trivial examples are [changing the plurality of a word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/796412/how-to-turn-plural-words-singular) or anything
>     relating to [natural language processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450493/natural-english-language-words).   In fact, the language
>     may be *required* for these questions.
> - Languages have their own [Unicode blocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_block). They can have tags.
> - Languages have different [encodings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding#Common_character_encodings). As much as we love [utf 8](http://www.utf8everywhere.org/), sometimes you're dealing with an old file, or a legacy system.
> - [Internationalization and localization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization) are just features.   I don't need to get i18n and L10n right to write a Turkish site if
>     that's the only language I'm supporting. I just want *my* language to
>     work.
> - [font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/font), [rtl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rtl), [utf-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/utf-8), etc can replace the language in many cases, but sometimes they assume you *already know the cause of
>     your problem*.   For example: Suppose my Japanese site "isn't working"
>     on a Kindle Touch. Did I mess the encoding? Am I using a wrong font?
>     Does the reader even have any Japanese fonts? If not, would a web font
>     work? Is there a third-party solution to get it to work?   When asking
>     a question, I probably don't know any of these.
> - Some "language features" are unique, or at least appear unique to their owners.   In Hebrew we have [nikud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12763476/ignoring-hebrew-vowels-when-comparing-strings) and [optional vowels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ktiv_hasar_niqqud),
>     for example. If I had problems with these, I wouldn't bother searching
>     for a general solution.   [Unicode collation algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_collation_algorithm) do make
>     these problems appear simple, but at the end require per-language
>     implementation.

Comment: // , I like your FARSIghted approach, @Aziz.

Comment: One might want to add that generally non-native speakers can hardly be trusted to make the decision whether the language tag is justified or not, given the quoted examples.

Comment: @0xC0000022L i tend to agree with you. A cleanup is always good but tag burnination is probably not the right approach here.

Comment: There are also non-Unicode, non-legacy encodings, notably including [Big5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big5) and [Shift JIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_JIS).

Answer (score 12):

This and any other language tags would be pretty useful in HTML or Unicode questions or question about language-specific encodings. Language specific collation, sorting, formatting come to mind too and that's just offthe top of my head. So in my opinion this and all other natural-language tags are useful and should be preserved.

Comment: They are only relevant if the specific language-tag is important because there are additional considerations in that one. So, most of them are noise.

Comment: Such as the language tag in [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33490856/2564301)? (Re-used from [the original discussion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/315838/2564301))

Comment: @Deduplicator, belive me, pretty much any language that doesn't fit in plain ASCII have additional considerations, from my experience with CJK and Russian and bunch of European languages. Or rather no, don't believe me. Just go read any article on collation.

Comment: @Jogware, that's just a bad tagging. You won't propose to remove `c++` tag if I present you with single mistagged question, will you?

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov: In what way is internationalization in russian so different from french? What are the additional things which will go wrong?

Comment: @Deduplicator, uh, you don't ever program outside of ASCII, do you? Let me tell you a few subjects that will be can be attributed only to single language: jamo composition, kanji radical lookup, simplified hanzi lookup. Or processes that will be vastly different in different natural languages: breaking words in stem/pre/suffix parts. That's your differences. Need more?

Comment: Are you even reading?

Comment: Seems you are not. Because I asked you about the specific language you named, not any and all others. That the specific rules about how to form a grammatically correct and sensible sentence differ between any two languages is irrelevant here, really.

Comment: @Deduplicator, just write me a universal collation function that will support Russian, French and Japanese in alphabet/romanization order (for example for school book). Come on: "internationalization is not so different", so you should fit it ten lines or so. Then feel free to come back with your smart comments.

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov: You are missing the point. Every language has a different collation-order (at least one), but that's not something special enough to warrant a tag for every language under the sun.

Comment: @Deduplicator, it is you who is missing the point: every language have tons of other features, not only collation. Generally people who work with processing some language are proficient in most of those different features, but have no clue how same features would work in other language. And those people will look for tags for that languages to answer. I can answer tags for inflection/collation/sorting/in-place conversion for "russian", I can answer tags for <insert list of 10-20 features> for "japanese". I will look for those tags. And I need them different from "persian".

Comment: Is this purely a hypothetical objection; or are some of the questions with the persian/farsi tags actually about this sort of issue?  If the latter, citing a few of them in your answers would probably improve their reception.

Comment: @DanNeely I clicked the tag and the first question is literally just that, [asking why a Word Cloud is behaving strangely with strings in Farsi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35058827/word-cloud-for-other-languages).

Comment: @Casey: That's a general issue with handling a word character by character, instead of as a whole.

Comment: @Deduplicator Well, great, but if you knew that already you wouldn't have to ask a question in the first place, now would you?

Comment: @Casey My point is that the question you cited is poor justification for the existance of [farsi], just [unicode] would suffice. I suspect there are others more fitting for this discussion, but you didn't highlight one of those.

Comment: @Deduplicator Well, I don't see that as sufficient, because if you knew "Unicode" was the issue you wouldn't pose the question that way.

Answer (score 10):

As someone who has done a lot of i18n work and dealt with language issues relating to programming-  there's a lot of language specific questions I could ask where a tag would be useful.  or example, a Korean language tag would be useful to talk about issues with character combination (when certain combos of letters reform into 1 different letter).  Or how to correctly implement tones and diaritics in Vietnamese, specifically with OS specific implementation issues (ever gotten a cursor stuck between 2 of those characters and hit delete?  Weird shit happens, and needs to be coded against).  Farsi has a few issues of its own.  All of these would seem to be valid tags to me.

Comment: If you could show how farsi is so far out of the ordinary in any of those aspects that it deserves its own tag, instead of trading in generalities that some languages might be tricky, that would make a good answer...

Comment: @Deduplicator I'd guess a significant portion of, say, PHP, or Java, or whatever, questions could be answered in a language-agnostic way; does that mean the tag should be removed from them?

Comment: @Casey - indeed, we need only one tag: [tag:turing-machine]. Who needs those pesky high-level languages anyway?

Comment: Yes, a significant amount of programming questions can be answered in a language-agnostic way, and many are, especially in the algorithm tag, or when it's about a cross-language framework. Still, the fact that Korean and Vietnamese have enough extra-issues you won't generally encounter with other languages does not show that the same holds for farsi. You say "Farsi has a few issues of its own", and while that may be true, *you fail to name them*. As this question is only about [farsi], that sharply limits the answers usefulness.

Comment: @Deduplicator I didn't write this answer, so I'm not sure who "you" is supposed to refer to.  The fact is, I don't know very much about Farsi, in particular.  Do you?  Do most of the people proposing the tag be deleted?  I'd think the fact that these issues exist for other languages, and that people seem to have questions that go "this or that thing works fine, except when I try text in Farsi," should be reason enough to be cautious about just deleting the tag.

Comment: @Casey Beeing cautious is fine, though one can go too far. And sorry, you are right, part of that comment should have been directed to the OP.

Comment: @Deduplicator: for Arabic, I think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28982577/utf-8-to-cp864-arabic-conversion makes a good example. An Arabic Shaper is needed to convert from non-contextual forms to presentational forms. Persian has the exact same issue.

Answer (score 6):

// , 1. We have tags for programming languages.

2. Many natural languages each have more inherent structural complexity even than programming languages.
3. Natural languages are a 'domain of application' of programming.
4. Any member of a 'domain of application' of programming which also has more structural complexity than most programming languages currently handle generally must have separate answers* on stackoverflow.
5. Any set of questions whose legitimate answers on stackoverflow that ought to be allowed to be separated by a criterion should allow that criterion as a tag.
6. Farsi is a member of the 'domain of application' of programming called 'natural languages.'

*... (hopefully I have made it possible to see where I'm trying to go with this)...*

n. Questions about applications specific to the Farsi language are a set of questions whose legitimate answers on stackoverflow that ought to be allowed to be separated by a criterion should therefore [per 5] allow that criterion as a tag.

Let me know in the comments which of these points I should expand!

IN SHORT: **If human languages were APIs, we'd allow them their own tags, right? Right? Maybe?**

*Assuming, of course, that the answers are on topic, not based on opinion only, yada yada yada...

Comment: // , I hope, dear reader, that I have not made it easy to miss my effort at the jokey joke-making in my answer and this comment...

Comment: Yes, if human languages were APIs, we probably would give them their own tags. They aren't though. Which makes this answer somewhat useless, unless I missed something profound you said somewhere hidden in the irrelevancies. (Considering this is upvoted, I hope so. And would appreciate something a bit more direct.)

Comment: @Deduplicator - telling every person whose answer you don't like their post is useless is probably not the best move.

Comment: @DeerHunter: Telling everyone what's missing to make it an answer to the question is a good thing. Now if that also got added.... *that* would be wonderful.

Comment: // , @Deduplicator, let me know in the comments which of these points I should expand! The, ah, "irrelevancies" are my attempt at a chain of reasoning from what we know about tags, in general, to apply that knowledge to Farsi. Also, because I wanted to keep the "IN SHORT" part, well, _short_, it does have an unstated premise or two.

Comment: @Deduplicator I urge you to create a tag of my API for nothingness written in all major programming languages, link can be found at the bottom. So my API can have a tag, and a natural language representing more than 100M people can't have? **mind blown** Here's my API: https://github.com/MrAudioGuy/nothing I thing `nothing` itself can be a suitable tag.

Comment: @Cunning: Don't get utterly ridiculous. Nathan: The point is that to justify a tag, there must be more than generic differences which are found between any two human language, there must actually be a significant difference relevant to programming, which means not the same kind of difference as in the other ones.

Comment: @Deduplicator just thought the idea is hilarious, because it is what it is advertised as, yet useless. I was just joking, but jokes aside, believe me tags about languages and cultures help improvements in software development and programming. I have suffered to work on projects for different cultures with rtl, non latin lettered, non anglo type of grammar, with a whole different calendar: yes I am talking about persian and searching the term persian helped me a lot in delivering those projects.

Comment: @Cunning: The question is whether this specific tag helps, not whether there are generally language-tags which are justified because that specific language (or group thereof) opens up yet another strange vista in the complexities which is i18n.

Answer (score 4):

Please keep all the language- and encoding-related tags. Seriously. Tagging doesn't cost you money, but improves searching. If you want to burninate human language related stuff, start with Unicode. Let's see how far you can go without it.

Comment: If we have a tag for everything, we have tags for nothing.

Comment: @Deduplicator: That doesn't even make *sense*. And this is coming from someone who agrees that Farsi needs to prove its worth as a tag.

Comment: @NicolBolas Think about it: If you have a tag for everything, what's the difference from a full-text-search? How do tags help cluster related questions when there's a different tag for every shade of meaning?

Comment: @Deduplicator: It was nonsense because nobody suggested having a tag for *everything*, or even a significant portion of that. I guess the more formal term would be "strawman", but either way, it's not helpful. A far better criticism of his post is to point out that tags aren't for *searching*.

Comment: @NicolBolas Well, might have been a bit too exaggerated.

Comment: Question, though -- how is Unicode a human language? Maybe I'm missing something obvious to you, but there's a huge difference. Once is a character set/encoding system for individual characters, the other is a phoneme and morpheme set for encoding meaning. Totally different.

Answer (score 2):

I think a lot of the replies on this question are missing something significant. That being the answer to the question:

What is a tag *for*?

Tags are *not* for aiding in searches. While I will never defend the Stack Overflow search engine, it does look at more things than just tags. So even without the Farsi tag, people can still find Farsi questions just by searching for them. Losing this tag will not make it harder for people to find solutions to problems involving Farsi.

And where SE's search engine fails, Google succeeds. So you can still find it one way or the other.

The purpose of a tag is to be a rallying point for a group of people who bring expertise to that subject. A tag should be something that an expert could explicitly *monitor*. Where a person who has domain expertise can frequently check *all* questions that mention this subject, since they could probably answer a percentage of them.

So one question of relevance here is this: does the use of Farsi, *in a programming context*, rise to that level? Does the use of Farsi in programming require such specific domain knowledge that there are experts in that field?

But even that alone is not sufficient. Not only must there be a body of domain expertise (such that an expert would reasonably want to patrol the tag), but the field should not be hierarchical. Allow me to explain.

My personal feeling (and I have little experience with Internationalization issues, so I may well be talking out of my ass) is that most of the issues that Farsi brings to programming are in the I18N domain: text formatting&layout, collation, encoding, and so forth. I suspect that most people who know solutions to the issues Farsi brings to these domains are experts *in those domains*, not specifically in Farsi.

That is, someone who knows about the collation rules in Farsi probably also has knowledge of the collation rules of many other languages. And if they don't know the answers, then as I18N experts, they probably know where the resources are to *find* the answer.

So my feeling is that Farsi questions could probably be placed under the specific domain that the question is asking about. Collation questions in the Farsi language use the [collation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/collation) tag. Text formatting/layout in Farsi use the appropriate tag for formatting and layout of text.

So what I feel needs to be demonstrated are these:

1. That Farsi issues in programming are of such significance that they have a body of expertise around them, such that those experts would benefit from having a tag.
2. That this body of expertise are not all (or mostly) also experts in I18N issues, and therefore would have found such and attended to such questions without the tag.

Comment: "[without the tag] people can still find Farsi questions just by searching for them" - How? Have you tried?

Comment: Let me tell you: before tags came in vogue there were hierarchical classification systems (Dewey, Universal etc.) They were explicitly meant to aid in searching in a vast body of knowledge. The thing is, people found that there are cross-links, multidisciplinary subjects etc. etc. There were facets, and only then came the tags. Tags are necessary to quickly winnow a slice from the body of knowledge, to use human brains instead of Google's algorithms in classification, and to track developments in the field by introducing new tags very quickly. ...

Comment: @DeerHunter: But SO doesn't need tags for classification. Indeed, most of SO's traffic comes from "Google's algorithms". Furthermore, even if it was what tags were for, that *still* doesn't justify the Farsi tag. After all, questions can only have 5 tags; why waste one on something ultra-specific, if you're also going to have I18N, Collation, or whatever else in *addition* to whatever language & library you're working with?

Comment: ... Everything else (communities etc.) comes next. Stack Overflow has tag communities because of its sheer size; most tag communities fit within [Dunbar's number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunbar%27s_number).